# Get info about foreign key on delete action

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, constraints, sybase, sap-ase

I have a Sybase database with two tables.
One table refer to another with a foreign key. 
I need to know - is this foreign declared with any `on cascade` option?

I have already tried:
`EXEC sp_helpconstraint <table_with_constraint>`
but this doesn't return any `on cascade` information. Is there any way to get this information from Sybase without creating fake records and deleting them?
`sysconstraints` table also keeps no information about cascade operations. What am I missing?

Server version is: ASE 15.x

Comment: Which version of ASE do  you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sybase ASE 15 does not support on cascade DDL so none of your foreign keys will have a cascade option.
If you want the delete or update on cascade functionality  you must implement a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if a foreign key has cascade properties you can use the following select:

```
  select (select user_name||'.'||table_name from sys.SYSTABLE a join sys.sysuserperms u on(a.creator = u.user_id) where a.table_id = SYSFOREIGNKEY.primary_table_id) primary_table,
           (select user_name||'.'||table_name from sys.SYSTABLE a join sys.sysuserperms u on(a.creator = u.user_id) where a.table_id = SYSFOREIGNKEY.foreign_table_id) foreign_table,
           SYSFOREIGNKEY."role" as fk_name,
           SYSTRIGGER.trigger_defn 
      from sys.SYSFOREIGNKEY key
      join sys.SYSTRIGGER key 
      join sys.systable 
      join sys.sysuserperms u on(systable.creator = u.user_id)
    where u.user_name in('dba')
    --  and SYSTRIGGER.foreign_table_id= 8141 
      --and SYSTRIGGER.foreign_key_id = 1
```